# Is the Yongnuo YN-E3-RT weather-sealed?

Tags: wireless-flash, wireless-triggers

I'm thinking of buying a Yongnuo YN-E3-RT instead of the Canon ST-E3-RT.  My one and only reason for getting the Yongnuo is because it allows off-camera second curtain sync (SCS) with my Canon 5D Mk III.  (I'm aware the Canon version 2 ST-E3-RT offers SCS, but SCS only works in conjunction with newer camera bodies and not the 5D Mk III, unfortunately.)

However, ideally, I also need the Yongnuo YN-E3-RT to be reasonably well weather sealed.  (I live and work in the UK!)

What are people's experiences using the Yongnuo YN-E3-RT in foul weather?  Is the foot effectively weather-sealed?  I know the battery compartment lacks a rubber gasket, but if necessary, I can put a plastic bag over the unit and control the flashes, as much as I need to, using the camera body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used mine under the rain but at least there is an attempt, for instance the user manual points at a dust/water cover for the hot-shoe:

[image]

This is a rubber ring that seals off the hot-shoe when the transmitter is locked in:

[image]

Can't tell if the buttons are as well designed....

Answer (score 1):

From the Yongnuo USA website:

> *"The transmitter also has dust and water resistance equivalent to
> EOS-1D series cameras."*

I have not used them myself...

Answer (score 0):

It's a radio transmitter. If you need to you can put a clear plastic bag over it and seal it to the camera body with gaffer tape. Gaffer tape leaves no residue behind. It's still easy to press the control buttons through the plastic. Or better yet, use a plastic cover made to fit over the flash and the camera. They're cheap and effective. I've never used the YN-E3-RT, but I have used the same method with a Flashpoint (Godox) R2 Pro Mark II transmitter.

The last Yongnuo flash I bought was a YN685. It has a big rubber chunk at the hot foot similar to the one on the YN-E3-RT that is supposed to seal off the connection to the camera's hot shoe. It was constantly falling off to the point I stopped putting it back on most of the time. Most of the time I was using the flash off camera via radio and the flash was mounted on a cold shoe.

Once I switched to the Godox system I needed to attach a Godox X1R-C to the YN685 and did place the rubber chunk on the flash before attaching it to the receiver. But if I'm shooting in any kind of wet weather, there's a plastic bag over my camera, lens, and flash/transmitter.

The whole idea that some things are "weather-sealed" and other things are "not weather-sealed" as if there is no in between is a false assumption. It's not a binary category. There are varying levels of weather/dust resistance. Try immersing the Canon ST-E3-RT in water and see how "weather sealed" it is. Then try getting Canon to replace it under warranty. As Roger Cicala has often said, "You can assume whatever you like, but when you send your lens/camera in for repair, ‘weather sealed’ still means ‘the warranty doesn’t cover water damage’."

Comment: I'm happy to use a plastic bag over the unit. But I'd rather not put any tape around the hot shoe in case I need to swap out the transmitter for an on-camera flash in a hurry. I'm most concerned about water getting in the camera hot shoe and causing the transmitter to malfunction.  The Canon gasket on some of their flashes seems to do a reasonable job of keeping water out.  I'm hoping the Yongnuo version may be similar.  It's not a good sign the Yongnuo gasket falls off easily, though.